# how to replace value of field when field is empty?

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2013

On my left schema, sometimes for the `StartTime` we will have no value whatsoever. Some examples of valid values would be:

```
1200
1320
2100
0900
```

When the input is blank, simply `<StartTime></StartTime>` the output I'd like to have is midnight, or `<StartTime>0000</StartTime>`

I understand that I can do this through a regular scripting functoid, but is this possible to do without code?

**Are there functoids which simply replace the original contents of the field with something else, allowing for further processing?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, just use a combination of Length+Equal/Logical Not/Value Mapping Functiods to pass either the received value (Length != 0) or 0000 (Length = 0).

Length -> GreaterThan(0) -> Value Mapping/Source -> Target

--and--

[Length -> GreaterThan(0)] -> LogicalNot -> ValueMapping/"0000" -> Target

Comment: can you please show a picture? im a beginer and dont have a full grasp yet of how to do if/then branches within the map without a custom functoid

Comment: @l--''''''---------'''''''''''' It's just linking Functoids.  Just try some things.  You can't break anything.  :)

Comment: the first case makes sense, but the second does not, in the second flow that you are showing here,where do we hardcode the `0000`?

Comment: @l--''''''---------'''''''''''' Please try some things.  We can't give you all the answers.